# PHP MVC for login form

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm working on website allowing to manage candidacies. 
Multiple features are already operational like advanced search, dynamic list of candidacies with ajax, sort, export content of candidacy in zip format in relation with GDPR. However, no architecture was developped for the moment.
So, from my login form, I would like to add MVC architecture.

Would I be correct in assuming that, the Model would contain the SQL select statements, the controller would handle the data e.g if (isset($_POST["identity"])) { and the view would contain the basic HTML form where the user would enter the data ?

The problem is that from my existing files, I don't really see how to add MVC.

My config.php will become model.php at the end, index.php, login.php are views, but for the controller, I am stuck ! :/

**config. php :**

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db = 'candidates';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

try
{
    $cnx = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die('Connection failed :'. $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

**login.php :**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include('template.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['flash']))
    {
        foreach($_SESSION['flash'] as $type => $message)
        {
            echo $message;
        }
        unset($_SESSION['flash']);
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        header('Location: ../index.php');
    }
?>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img id="imgNavbar" src="../img/candidacy.jpg" alt="Home"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                              <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item" style="margin-left: 0px">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Connect</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <form method="post" action="checkLogin.php">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="card card-container">
                        <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="../img/avatar.png" />
                        <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
                        <form class="form-signin">
                            <span id="formIdentity" class="formIdentity"></span>
                            <input type="text" id="identity" name="identity" class="form-control" placeholder="Your identity" autofocus>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Your password">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit" id="submitBtn" name="submit" onclick="checkForm(this)">Connect</button>
                        </form><!-- /form -->
                        <a href="forgotPassword.php" class="forgot-password">
                            Forgot password ?
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- /card-container -->
                </div><!-- /container -->
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**checkLogin.php**

```
<?php
require('config/config.php');

session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(isset($_POST['identity']) && isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $stmt = $cnx->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE nameUser = :username");
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $_POST['identity'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();
        $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $result = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($result > 0)
        {
            if(password_verify($_POST['password'], $users['passwordUser']))
            {
                $token = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
                $_SESSION['user'] = $users;
                $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
                $_SESSION['start'] = time();
                $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (120 * 60);

                header('Location: ../index.php');
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['flash']['info'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Check your information !</div>";
                header('Location: ../login.php');
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            $_SESSION['flash']['connect'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Non-existent user !</div>";
            header('Location: ../login.php');
            exit(0);
        }

        $stmt->closeCursor();
    }
    if(empty($_POST['identity']) || empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $_SESSION['flash']['empty'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Fill in the fields please !</div>";
        header('Location: ../login.php');
        exit(0);
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php :**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        session_start();
    }
    ob_start();

    include('template.php');
    require('config/config.php');

    if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $currentTime = time();
        if($currentTime < $_SESSION['expire'])
        {
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container header">
            <div id="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                      <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img id="imgNavbar" src="../img/candidacy.jpg" alt="Home"></a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                              <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="../index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                              </li>
                              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $_SESSION['user']['nameUser']?></a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                     <a class="dropdown-item" href="myProfile.php">My Profile</a>
                                </div>
                              </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="listCandidacies.php">List of candidacies</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="addCandidacy.php">Add a candidacy</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Disconnect</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <h3 class="text-uppercase">
                        <strong>Welcome to candidacy <br>space !</strong>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
        }
        else
        {
            unset($_SESSION['user']);
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: ../login.php');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        unset($_SESSION['user']);
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: ../login.php');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I believe you don’t just learn how to apply MVC to a specific problem, but either, you learn the concept and theory behind. You can have a look for *basics* in [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm).

Moreover, it is usually advised to use a framework so you wouldn’t unintentionally break some of the design pattern concepts.

Concerning your case, I would do it this way:

Models:

1. User
2. DatabaseConnector

Controllers:

1. LoginPageController
2. IndexController

Views:

1. Login
2. Index

Comment: I also would recommend using framework. Maybe `codeigniter` for beginners is OK.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that using a framework for that project is not recommanded :/

Comment: @D.Dimitrov Yeah, it's a good one. But I don't wanna turn the question into a software recommendation survey, you know.

Comment: @Maestro I was just saying. Nevertheless, I have proposed what can you do in your case.